# tlmgr_install: package footnote not present in repository

Tags: r, tinytex, tlmgr

I am trying to install package footnote using the following commands:

```
library(tinytex)
tlmgr_install("footnote")
```

However it throws the following error:

> tlmgr_install: package footnote not present in repository.

Any help, please.

Comment: Looking at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341789/tlmgr-packages-not-present-in-repository and https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnote, it may be that you need something like `tlmgr_install("mdwtools")` which the TeX stack exchange answer seems to imply would provide the package `footnote`?